# List within tabBar, remove the margin around list

Tags: list, sencha-touch, tabbar

I started using Sencha touch some days ago, and I am starting to learn how to use it. But now i have seem to found a problem, which i cannot solve myself.

I have used a template by "nelson" to create a PhoneGap app. In this template there are 5 bottom tabs, and within one of these tabs, there is a page with Two tabs docked to the top. Inside one of these tabs i would like to place a list. I have succeeded putting the list there, but it doesn't look very good. There is a huge margin around the list, and the headers seem very large IMO...

You can see an image of the problem here:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=30484&d=1325793060

And my code is posted right here:

```
ToolbarDemo.views.Homecard = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {    title: "Butikker",
iconCls: "home",
initComponent: function() {
Ext.apply(this, {
dockedItems: [{
xtype: "toolbar",
title: "Butikker",
ui: 'blue'
}
]
});
    Ext.apply(this, {
        defaults: {
            styleHtmlContent: true
        },
              tabBar : { 
              layout : { 
              pack : 'center' 
              } 
              },
        items: [{


            title: 'TabPanels',
                layout: Ext.is.Phone ? 'fit' : {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'left',
                pack: 'center'
                },
                items: [{
                        xtype: 'list',
                        store: store,
                        itemTpl: '<div class="contact"><strong>{firstName}</strong> {lastName}</div>',
                        grouped: true,
                        indexBar: true
                        }]


        },{
            title: 'Toolbars',
            scroll: 'vertical',
            html: '<p>Toolbars can be used as a title bar or as a container for buttons,   or you can mix and match both of these functions.</p>'
        }]
    });
    ToolbarDemo.views.Homecard.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
}
});


Ext.reg('homecard', ToolbarDemo.views.Homecard);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ToolbarDemo.views.Homecard = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {
    fullscreen : true, // or false
    title: "Butikker",
    iconCls: "home",
    initComponent: function() {
    ...
    ...
```

I hope it helps.